# Xcode 6 Problems with device sizes/constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, constraints

I am building a single view application with 12 different view controllers. I built all of the view controllers in "any width" and "any height" and added all constraints for each page and also first ran the simulator with an iPhone 6. However when I switch to other devices to run in the simulator, smaller and larger, the images I have on the view controllers become very distorted and the font sizes become disproportioned with the rest of the screen, despite adding in all necessary constraints. Do I have to redesign each view controller to fit each size (for example regular width and regular height for iPad or compact width and regular height for iPhones in portrait, etc.)? Or is there another way to maybe get all of the images/ font sizes into proportion with each screen size, again small and large? Thanks

Comment: I think it might help to see some relevant example code. Not all - just what is nececarry to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are fine in this case, you shouldn't have to redesign every view for each device size. For your images, try changing them from `size to fit` to `aspect fit` or `aspect fill` in the right-hand pane in Storyboard. This will keep their aspect ratios intact. I suggest starting out with using `reset to suggested constraints` on all views that you can before you fully get the hang of constraints. This will generally work most of the time.

Comment: The aspect fill was the one that worked! Thanks very much

Comment: Anytime. And I see that you're new to stack overflow so welcome! Also, don't forget to mark this answer solved if it helped, thanks!